# How to add a timestamp in java on a pane

Tags: java, javafx, timestamp, pane

I am currently working on this assignment and I can not seem to get this program to run even though I don't have any errors really popping up ? I am trying to add a time stamp to the pane as well but every time I add the "ts" name for the time stamp to the Pane or Hbox's get children code it goes red.. I am not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong if anyone can point me in the right direction id greatly appreciate it...

```
package PCK1;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.Timestamp;    
import java.util.Date;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class MainClass
{

    public static void start(Stage stage)
    {
    
    // Time Stamp
    Date date = new Date();  
     Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(date.getTime());  
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
       System.out.println(formatter.format(ts));
   
    //Create a Circle
    Circle c1 = new Circle(75,100,20);  



    //Create a Pane
    Pane p = new Pane();
    p.setMinSize(100, 150);
    p.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill( Color.rgb(190, 220, 190), null, null) 
    ));
    p.getChildren().addAll(c1);

   
   
    //Create a Button
    Button btnUp = new Button("Up");
    btnUp.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {double y = c1.getCenterY();
    y -= 20.0;
    c1.setCenterY(y);
     });

    Button btnDown = new Button("Down");
    btnDown.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {double y = c1.getCenterY();
    y += 20.0;
    c1.setCenterY(y);
     });



    //Create a HBox
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.getChildren().addAll(btnUp, btnDown, p, ts);
    hb.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(150,200,150),null,null)));
    hb.setMinSize(100, 50);
    hb.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

  

 
    Scene scene = new Scene(hb);
  
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.setTitle("JavaFx");
      stage.setWidth(250);
      stage.setHeight(250);
      stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it goes red"?

Comment: Is `TimeStap` a node? Is it a POJO?

Comment: btw: don't use the outdated Date (and related) classes, instead use the new LocalDate/Time

Comment: The [tutorial trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for the time classes you should be using.  Please spend some time to study it and adjust your code accordingly.  The time API selection is a best practice issue rather than the immediate cause of your (multiple)  compile and runtime issues with your current code, which will not function.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer for displaying a timestamp

Specifically, for the timestamp question, see the following example code:

```
private Label createTimestampLabel() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String formattedTimestamp = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);

    return new Label(formattedTimestamp);
}
```

It uses the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) APIs explained in the [Oracle Date Time tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) to get the current time from LocalDateTime and format it as a String using a standard format.

It sets the formatted timestamp string as the text of a Label node.

Now that the returned element is a Node, it can be placed in the scene graph without generating the compile error you saw in your original example.

Using the `java.time` APIs is preferred over the `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.util.Date` code in your question. You are not working with SQL, so you should not be using `java.sql.Timestamp`.  The `java.time` classes also have many improvements over obsolete date and time functions used in other Java packages like `java.util`.

#### Answer in context with a re-write of your example code

There were a lot of things about the provided example application that were either wrong or annoyed me.

So I re-wrote it to match a bit more closely how I would normally write such an application.

There are maybe a hundred different small decisions made in the choices for how to implement the re-write and explaining them all here would be too verbose.

Hopefully, you can compare the re-write to your original code, note some of the differences, and learn some things from it.

[image: example app]

**GraphicControlApp.java**

```
package org.example.javafx.demo.graphiccontrol;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GraphicControlApp extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GraphicController graphicController = new GraphicController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(graphicController.getUI());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Interactive Graphic Control Demonstration");
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

**GraphicController.java**

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 * UI creator and controller for application logic.
 *
 * Normally, most UI elements would be defined externally in FXML,
 * however, for a simple application, we define the UI via private functions in this class.
 */
public class GraphicController {
    // amount to move the circle across the surface on interaction.
    private static final double MOVEMENT_DELTA = 20.0;

    // default spacing between UI elements.
    private static final double SPACING = 10;

    // normally the styles would be configured in an external css stylesheet,
    // but we place the background definitions here for a simple application.
    private static final Color SURFACE_COLOR = Color.rgb(190, 220, 190);
    private static final Background surfaceBackground = createBackground(SURFACE_COLOR);
    private static final Color APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.rgb(150, 200, 150);
    private static final Background appBackground = createBackground(APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR);

    private Button up;
    private Button down;

    /**
     * @return the complete layout for the application with event handlers attached for logic control.
     */
    public Pane getUI() {
        Circle circle = new Circle(75, 100, 20);

        Pane surface = createSurface(circle);
        HBox controls = createControls(circle);
        Label timestampLabel = createTimestampLabel();

        Pane layout = createLayout(surface, controls, timestampLabel);
        attachKeyboardHandlers(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    /**
     * Create a label formatted with the current time in ISO standard format (e.g. '2011-12-03T10:15:30')
     *
     * @return label with the current timestamp.
     */
    private Label createTimestampLabel() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String formattedTimestamp = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);

        return new Label(formattedTimestamp);
    }

    /**
     * Create a surface on which a circle can move.
     *
     * @param circle the circle which can move on the surface.
     * @return the created surface.
     */
    private Pane createSurface(Circle circle) {
        Pane surface = new Pane();

        surface.setMinSize(100, 150);
        surface.setBackground(surfaceBackground);
        surface.getChildren().addAll(circle);

        // we must define a clip on the surface to ensure that elements
        // in the surface do not render outside the surface.
        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
        clip.widthProperty().bind(surface.widthProperty());
        clip.heightProperty().bind(surface.heightProperty());
        surface.setClip(clip);

        return surface;
    }

    private VBox createLayout(Pane surface, HBox controls, Label timestampLabel) {
        VBox layout = new VBox(SPACING, controls, surface, timestampLabel);

        layout.setBackground(appBackground);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(SPACING));

        VBox.setVgrow(surface, Priority.ALWAYS);

        return layout;
    }

    /**
     * Create controls which can control the movement of a circle.
     *
     * @param circle the circle which can be controlled
     * @return the created controls with handlers attached for circle movement control.
     */
    private HBox createControls(Circle circle) {
        up = new Button("Up");
        up.setOnAction(e -> moveVertically(circle, -MOVEMENT_DELTA));

        down = new Button("Down");
        down.setOnAction(e -> moveVertically(circle, MOVEMENT_DELTA));

        return new HBox(SPACING, up, down);
    }

    private void moveVertically(Circle circle, double delta) {
        double y = circle.getCenterY();

        // we only restrict movement in the up direction,
        // but allow unlimited movement in the down direction
        // (even if that movement would mean that the circle would extend totally
        // outside the current visible boundary of the surface).
        if ((y + delta) < 0) {
            return;
        }

        circle.setCenterY(y + delta);
    }

    /**
     * Adds standard keyboard handling logic to the UI.
     * 
     * Handlers are attached to the relevant scene whenever 
     * the scene containing the UI changes.
     *
     * @param layout the UI which will respond to keyboard input.
     */
    private void attachKeyboardHandlers(Pane layout) {
        EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case UP -> { up.requestFocus(); up.fire(); }
                case DOWN -> { down.requestFocus(); down.fire(); }
            }
        };

        layout.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (oldScene != null) {
                oldScene.removeEventFilter(
                        KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                        keyEventHandler
                );
            }

            if (newScene != null) {
                newScene.addEventFilter(
                        KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                        keyEventHandler
                );
            }
        });
    }

    private static Background createBackground(Color surfaceColor) {
        return new Background(new BackgroundFill(surfaceColor, null, null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show the timestamp as text with the `TextField` ([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html)) :

```java
TextField myText = new TextField();
myText.setText("Time: " + formatter.format(ts));
// set what you want to the TextField object: padding, size, color etc...
p.getChildren().addAll(myText);
```